# Ionic InAppBrowser no done/close button iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

Please see attached snippet I am using for inappbrowser. I have used '_blank' with location and toolbar=yes the link opens in the inappbrowser, but there is no back button or done button.
I have tried replacing '_blank' with '_self', but this doesn't make any difference.
Since this wasn't working for me, I decided it's best to open the link in the system browser and replaced '_self' with '_system', but this does not work. The link does not open at all.
All 3 run fine when i test it in the browser, but when simulating it on the iOS simulator or when testing on the iOS device, I face the above issues.

I have read a lot of posts on stack overflow and on the ionic forum and tried almost all solutions provided, but none have worked for me. It seems to be a bug in using ionic with iOS. Anyone have any other solutions?

`〈a ng-href="https://facebook.com" target="_self" ng-click="cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://facebook.com','_self', 'location=yes, toolbar=yes'); return false;"〉test〈/a〉`

Ionic 1, Xcode Version 8.3.2, iOS 9, cordova-plugin-inappbrowser spec="^1.7.1"

Comment: ionic1 or ionic2

Comment: Ionic 1, Xcode Version 8.3.2

Comment: `<a class="item" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
                click here
            </a>`

Comment: check this https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/07/launch-external-urls-ionicframework/

Comment: <a class="item" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;"> click here </a>

This is not working. Redirects to the login page somehow

Comment: which plugin you are  using?

Comment: cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the problem for me. Add the following code is in your config.xml file if it isn't already present:

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

Add the href depending on the hyperlink you are using in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked in my previous app. code is working fine.

check this github repo for example code: https://github.com/varunaaruru/ionic1-inappbrowser

install the plugin :

> **ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser**

in html file :

```
<a  href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
    click here
</a>
```

you can use `blank` or `self` in place of `system`

Comment: This is exactly what I have been doing for the past 2 days, but the 'close'/'done' options does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below  lines:

```
   const iosoption: InAppBrowserOptions = {
      zoom: 'no',
      location:'yes',
      toolbar:'yes',
      clearcache: 'yes',
      clearsessioncache: 'yes',
      disallowoverscroll: 'yes',
      enableViewportScale: 'yes'
    }

 if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      browser = this.inAppBrowser.create(this.ValidateUsers, '_blank', iosoption);
    }
```